# npm install stuck - extract:rxjs: verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking

Tags: node.js, npm

I receive this message when running `npm install`:

> npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.6.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
>
> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we
>   recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
>
> npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
>
> [                ..] | extract:rxjs: verb gentlyRm don't care about contents; nuking C:\Users\oscar\Documents\project

After this npm hangs. Tried on two computers and the same thing happens Worked last week and we have not changed anything in `package.json` since then.

Using NPM 3.10.10 on Windows 10.

This is our `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project.Application",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "//": "NOTE! Both webpackcp and webpackbo scripts are needed for build server to work correctly",
  "scripts": {
    "webpackcp": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config webpack.clientportal.config.js --mode development",
    "webpackcpprod": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config webpack.clientportal.config.prod.js --mode production",
    "webpackbo": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config webpack.backoffice.config.js --mode development",
    "startcp": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server --config webpack.clientportal.config.js --mode development",
    "startbo": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server --config webpack.backoffice.config.js --mode development",
    "start": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server --config webpack.backoffice.config.js --mode development",
    "webpack": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config webpack.backoffice.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "jest -i",
    "trans:compile": "tsc -p .  --target ES6 --module es6 --jsx preserve --outDir Extracted --moduleResolution node",
    "trans:extract": "babel  \"Extracted/**/*.jsx\"",
    "trans:manage": "node scripts/translationRunner.js",
    "lint": "tslint --project .",
    "lint:fix": "tslint --project . --fix"
  },
  "author": "Users",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "agentkeepalive": "^3.4.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.44",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-intl-translations-manager": "^5.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.20.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "recompose": "^0.26.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "ssl-root-cas": "^1.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.7",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-intl": "^2.3.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.22",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.15.1",
    "@types/recompose": "^0.24.6",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "ts-jest": "^22.4.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.1.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-uglify-js-plugin": "^1.1.9"
  },
  "jest": {
    "automock": false,
    "setupFiles": [
      "./scripts/testUtils/raf-shim.js"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./scripts/testUtils/setupTests.js",
    "transform": {
      ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/Scripts/testUtils/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^Root/(.*)": "<rootDir>/$1",
      "^Scripts/(.*)": "<rootDir>/Scripts/$1",
      "^Features/(.*)": "<rootDir>/Features/$1",
      "^Shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/Features/Shared/$1",
      "^Styles/(.*)": "<rootDir>/Features/Client/Styles/$1"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/NotUsed/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling `Node.js 6.11.4 LTS` and installed `Node.js 8.11.1 LTS` with `NPM 5.6.0`.

https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: my node is 10.16 and npm is 6.9

Comment: If you vote down please say why. Very hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: that does not fix the original issue, people with much newer versions you suggest still reproduce it